# NAS setup with Ubuntu

Tags: nas

First of all, I have read *Simple NAS setup for Ubuntu*, which is a bit beyond my needs at the moment.

Briefly, I am new to Ubuntu Linux as some of you already know. I need to build a NAS with Ubuntu - on which I can, at least for the time being, store files from my 2 Win 7 64 bit computers - many, many TB's of NTFS files. Is there a "how to" on that for a newbie such as myself?

Any additional software or interface required? (My network is Gigabit - router and switch, wired only.)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same and so far as I have heard there is a software which names is Synology, I have not installed it but I may do it. Also I found another software which names is freenasa, you can find it here http://www.freenas.org/, 
if I find something that could help us I will let you know, good luck buddy!!!!

Comment: Freenas is rather a Complete distribution, that is made for NAS server only!

Comment: Ohhh I see, I am sorry them

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two options both could be setup on existing Ubuntu installation.

- Simple/Quick: [Samba (MS Windows Share)](https://askubuntu.com/q/310180/26246), Installed by default with Ubuntu Desktop Edition.
- Advanced/Full NAS: [Zentyal Development Edition](https://wiki.zentyal.org/wiki/Installation_Guide), Go with installation from repository.

This question