# How do I share a folder between linux installs?

Tags: 13.04, samba

I've included the following in `/etc/sambe/smb.comf` so that i can edit files on our webserver from a Windows machine -

```
[websites]
    comment = Websites
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    path = /var/www/html/
    valid users = dgard
```

However, I've now installed Ubuntu (13.04) on to my machine and I wish to connect to the path specified above from it, but I cannot find out how.

I've tried `Connect to Server` from `Nautilus` with the following, but it fails -

```
sftp://dgard@webserver.local/var/www/html
```

Can anyone please let me know what I need to do? Thanks.

**Note:** my webserver does not have a desktop installed.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network

Comment: Thanks, but my webserver does not have a desktop, so I have to do it via terminal.

Comment: Please note also that I've amended my question after trying something from the question you tagged.

Comment: You either use samba, FTP or whatever file sharing method you want to use, not all at the same time. Please edit your question and let us know which of them you want, and how you plan to accomplish this. Be very verbose.

Comment: I would use NFS between 2 linux systems: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo It will retain permissions for on; samba is for windows<>linux.

Comment: SSH (and sftp) is probably the easiest and safest way to access a remote machine and its files. Have you installed openssh-server on the server?

Comment: Could you try the IP address of the server instead of `@webserver.local` and see if that works? Also try `sftp dgard@webserver.local:/var/www/html` in a terminal and update your wuestion with what error messages you get.

Answer (score 0):

To access a samba share you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Nautilus to open the location bar then type:

```
smb://webserver.local/websites
```

It will then ask for authentication and mount the shared folder.

Use server's IP address if have trouble accessing by name.