# Share Windows 8.1 Folder with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, windows, samba, sharing

I have two standalone PC's. One is Windows 8.1 and the other is Ubuntu 14.04. I have a working network between the two. Each machine can ping the other and I have Internet shared via Ethernet from the Windows machine to the Linux machine. One thing I can't seem to get right however is the sharing of a folder.

I have installed samba etc and followed numerous forums and so called solutions but none of them seem to work. When I try to access the Windows machine from the Linux machine it give the error:

```
Unhandled error message: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Have you seen this, it looks like the answer to your problem: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/how-to-fix-failed-to-retrieve-share-list-from-server-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-when-file-sharing-with-windows/ Just the first thing Google suggested when I searched for this problem.

Comment: I have tried that already, no success unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

Answer (score 0):

1. Share the folder on windows machine to all users.
2. Change the settings in windows machine:

   Go to Control Panel > Network and sharing center > Change advanced sharing settings > Enable Turn Off password protect sharing option.

   **NOTE:** Make sure the folder's Properties > Security includes Guest. Folders in C:\Users generally don't include that user.

   [This will allow sharing of files on network without knowing the username and password of windows machine]
3. Now try to access the folder from ubuntu.

reference: [How to access shared folder without giving username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442846/how-to-access-shared-folder-without-giving-username-and-password)