# How can a share storage between Linux, Windows, and Mac

Tags: file-sharing, drive, sharing

How can I share an internal hard drive across a network with both Windows and Mac with guest read and write permissions?

Comment: "Best way" is too broad and subjective. You can use any of several protocols samba, nfs, http, ftp, sshfs (ssh). "best" depends on your needs (ro, rw, one or two way file transfer) and security considerations.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network for Linux-Windows file sharing.

Comment: Why don't you make a FAT32 partition on your hard drive?

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste FAT partition does not share across the network. OP wants something along the lines of samba

Comment: Oh. I thought he meant with dual-boot. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

I use Samba for sharing files between Windows and my Linux machines, I can't speak to OSX, however.

Comment: This is not an answer. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network for an example of the question about Windows and Linux machine.

Comment: I have tried the built in file sharing which seems to work but when I go to do it for the entire drive I cannot change the permissions for guest to read and write

Comment: How to do this for the entire drive will depend on the partitions in that drive. If you have multiple partitions, you have to handle them separately. If you have a single partition mounted as `/` then changing the permission for that partition and all the system sub folders will make the Ubuntu system unbootable. It is not a good idea to let guests read and write to your system folder.