# I cant access Ubuntu from Windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, sharing

I read and followed [easy install](http://lifehacker.com/5919558/turn-an-old-computer-into-a-networked-backup-streaming-or-torrenting-machine-with-ubuntu) instructions for sharing files with Ubuntu.

I have three computers, Windows 7 64-bit home premium, Windows Vista and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My problem is that I cant access Ubuntu. When I open Explorer, go to Network, I can see all three computers but as soon as I click on Ubuntu box appears. It says :

Windows cannot access  \ ( my computer name here ) ...

What should I do ?

Comment: Did you install SAMBA on your Ubuntu box?

Comment: You may need to reboot the Ubuntu machine. You may also try the `sudo net usershare list` command to list the defined shares.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but didnt work.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network/310201#310201

Answer (score 1):

probably you don't have any user configured in smb.conf and/or your workgroup is not defined correctly.

1. Edit smb.conf with `gedit` or `nano`

   `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`
2. Edit or Add workgroup, in Windows as default is: `WORKGROUP`

   `workgroup = WORKGROUP`
3. Check if are directories to share declared in smb.conf

find a structure like this:

```
[folder_name_in_windows]
 comment = comment
 path = /home/public
 public = yes
 writable = no
```

1. Add user to SMB via shell after create an Ubuntu user without privileges and with `your_user` name.

   `sudo smbpasswd -a your_user`

Then, enter password or hit Enter to create the user without password.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried all your tips but I still have the same problem. "Windows cannot access \\..."

Comment: Sorry I forget that you need create the user in Ubuntu after ` sudo smbpasswd -a your_user` The user and password must be the same in Ubuntu and Samba. Try this and let me know.

Comment: I dont know so much about these things. Can you tell me how to create user in ubuntu ?

Comment: Sure `sudo adduser desired_username` and ask questions about Real Name and password

Comment: I tried still no luck.

Comment: Guys, I installed ubuntu again and followed your instructions. Now its working. Thanks for everyone 

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!