# How to share files in local network?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I'm trying share files between two computers with Ubuntu in my home, but I cannot get it.

I try to explain what I do until now

1- I have activated the Sharing Folders services using: sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn

And I have created a folder called Public, and I give it share permissions for sharing, I did the same in the other computer.

But It don't work

2- I install Samba and Samba Config and I added the folder to Samba Server.

But It don't work.

I created a Workgroup with the same name in two computers without success

When I try to enter in the local network asked me for a password

Can anyone explain me how I can share folder between two Ubuntu Computers  in a home network step by step.

Thank You

Comment: Samba is intended for sharing between windows and ubuntu. For sharing in between Ubuntu I would suggest `nfs`. See https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html Takes about 10 min. to setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share files through the local network?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed python you can try `SimpleHTTPServer`. For this

```
cd /folder/to/share
```

And then,

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This will allow sharing through port 8000. The other machine can access the files using http://"IP of first machine":8000

Answer (score 0):

You may utilize this [open source file synchronizing software - syncthing](https://syncthing.net/).

- It is easy to configure
- Very much simple to maintain/operate for long runs
- Can easily add multiple machines(computer/mobile of most operating systems) as backup/source as if needed

Also i encourage you to self-explore more from the existing official documentations