# How to share my home folder between two Ubuntu PCs via ethernet cable

Tags: file-sharing

I have two PCs, both running Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit, and an ethernet cable connecting them. I want to share files between them so that I can access both home folders easily. I have installed Dukto but it can only send files. What is the easiest way to do that without going through samba configuration and stuff (too difficult for me). I have a cyber cafe and I need this feature most. please help and be precise. I would be happier if I can do this through a GUI. By the way I have a 3G connection and I have managed to  share network connection via ethernet cable.

What should I do?

Comment: See [the "Ubuntu to Ubuntu" part of the answer to this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network/310201#310201). Even though the question is for WiFi, a wired network should not be very different.

Answer (score 0):

Samba is not difficult just install it :

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba python-glade2 gksu
```

You can follow this tutorial :

[Site](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/ubuntu1404-file-sharing-samba/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use caja or nautilus file browser you can directly type the following in the file browser location bar and save it as a bookmark.

```
ssh://username@ipaddress/home/userHomeDirectory/
```

For example, I have two computers: A (10.0.0.10) and B (10.0.0.20) . I access B from A by typing ssh://sahil@10.0.0.20/home/sahil/ in A's caja/nautilus and vice versa. The bookmark for this really comes really handy.