# Desktop / Laptop network startup

Tags: networking

What I wish to do 
Have may desktop and laptop work as a network together on start up of each device.
Maybe a VPN ( I know really nothing about or how to set one up )
I just wish to get file from one computer to the other and save files on both basically make two into one sort of. so when I start the computer or computers I can read and write to both

Desktop
Ubuntu 14.10 gnome with a D-Link DSL-G604T modem
Samba Loaded
yes I believe the modem is a router http://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=192.

Laptop WIN 8.1
wireless driver

What more info is needed to help
Thanks
Chris

Comment: do you have a router ? What are you trying to do? What do you meant you want them to be networked together?

Comment: yes I believe the modem is a router http://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=192.

Comment: I just wish to get file from one computer to the other and save files on both basically make two into one sort of. so when I start the computer or computers I can read and write to both

Comment: Use samba on Ubuntu or file sharing on windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest and fastest way* to share files between 2 computers is  [NitroShare](http://nitroshare.net/downloads/).  It works on Windows, Ubuntu and even on fruity-flavoured OSes...  **;-)**

There is also a PPA (`ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev`) if you want the *development* version... The downloads in the link above are stable!

Just install it on both machines and that's it!

Go to the dash:

[image]

and start `nitroshare` (or add it in the `Startup Applications` on Ubuntu and the `Startup Programs` on Windows) and a little icon like this: [image] will show up in your panel at the top of your screen and that's all you need to start sending files from one machine to the other and vice versa...