# Network Share Ubuntu 15.04 Not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, 15.04, shared-folders

I have a 1TB drive inside my desktop (running Ubuntu 15.04) that serves as a network share in my home. I have done the following to it

```
  chmod -R +775 /media/<me>/<share>
  chown -R <me>:share /media/<me>/<share>
  adduser <me> share
  adduser <GF> share
```

Then gone into the Disk's Properties and Chosen to share it over the network. However When try to connect from it from both our laptops running 14.04.2 LTS it can never connect even though we are using our logins from the Desktop.

Other posts relating to this issue are years old and have not gotten me ny responses. As this is the first time I have attempted to share something over the network on Linux I would greatly appreciate any help you could offer. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
When trying the steps mentioned from the post commented by the moderator I recieved an error that I do not have permission to access that location. This makes no sense beacuse I made a group for this drive, added ourselves to that group and gave us rwx permission on that drive.

in the connect to sever dialog I entered the following

```
  sftp://<gf>@192.168.blah.blah/<share>
```

AND

```
  sftp://<gf>@192.168.blah.blah/media/<me>/<share>
```

I am familiar with VSFTPD but don't think that's practical being as I dont think I need an FTP server when Ubuntu has something built in to accomplish this.

**UPDATE2:** Thanks to user68186 for working with me on this! To make my configuration a little Clearer I have the following

OS Drive 
       /dev/sdc - The OS Drive

The Share Drive:
      /dev/sdc - The Share Drive Itself ext4
      /dev/sda1 - The ONLY Partition on /dev/sdc (Share Drive) ext4

What I have done So far: http://pastebin.com/2CHZr42A

now I just need to make it accessible to users on my home network!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1: Create a mount point for the partition to be shared (`sda1` in this case)

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and create an empty folder called `shared` in not there:

```
sudo mkdir /media/shared
```

Find the UUID of the partition you want to share:

```
sudo blkid
```

copy the UUID of the partition you want to share (`/dev/sda1` in this case).

Make a backup of `/etc/sftab` and then edit the file

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.original
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line:

```
UUID=your-UUID-here /mnt/shared ext4 defaults 0 1
```

Use the actual UUID you had copied before instead of `your-UUID-here`.

To make the changes you made take effect, run the command:

```
sudo mount -a
```

## Step 2: Give everyone read and write permission for the `shared` partition

```
sudo chmod -R +777 /mnt/shared
```

## Step 3: Install ssh-server if not installed

**sftp is part of ssh and works with Ubuntu to Ubuntu file sharing** If you are using Windows in the laptop, see [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network) for using the `samba`protocol that works with Windows.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

## Step 4: Create a bookmark for the shared desktop drive in the laptop

Log into the laptop as `gf`

Open Nautilus and find the Menu item "Connect to server".

[image]

Under the server address enter. This assumes `gf` has an account in the desktop, if not replace `gf` with the user-ID of the desktop account holder below:

```
sftp://`gf`@192.168.blah.blah/mnt/shared
```

Press `Connect`. You will see a password dialog box:

[image]

Enter the password associated with `gf` (or the desktop user_ID) and select if you want the password is to be remembered or not. Again click Connect.

Now you should see your shared desktop drive.

Notice there is a new entry under **Network** on the left panel of Nautilus that begins with the user_ID used to connect to the shared folder. Right click on it and choose "Add Bookmark" to create a permanent bookmark for your laptop's home folder in the Nautilus of the Desktop.

Follow the same process for other users such as `me`.

Hope this helps