# Sharing files and folders between two pcs ubuntu and windows

Tags: samba, file-sharing, shared-folders, sharing

I have pc and laptop and I am using ubuntu 14.04 beside windows xp sp3 on both devices. I tried to share folders between them .

1. I installed Samba .
2. Set a user and password .
3. Set folders as shared (on ntfs partitions ) on both devices.
4. Tried to get into Workgroup network but keeping ask password and do not response when I entered the password that I set on samba or user password.

I can get into shared files on windows using Ubuntu only but not vice versa.
I tried Ubuntu-Ubuntu from desktop keep asking basswd and from laptop do nothing [not working with me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-using-a-wireless-network)
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

While I am pretty sure that any filesystem can be mounted in a Linux operating system (including NTFS, FAT32, FAT16), Windows does not see Linux
filesystems (e2fs, e3fs, reiserfs, etc). 
  A possible solution could be to make a folder on the Windows system and 
save files to be shared to that folder while in the Linux system. This actually
makes viewing 'shared' files viewable (workable? editable?) in both systems.

```
                 Hope this helps, Craig
```

Answer (score 0):

you did use smbpassword to set the user password right?
The user password and the samba password are different in linux

To create initially
sudo smbpasswd -a nameuser

or if added remove -a to change passwOrd

in /etc/samba/smb.conf
set workgroup
encrypt password to. True
Passdb backend tdbsam

Then define an entry at the end
[Data]
comment = data
path = /somewhere/data
guest ok = no
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
users = seb frank

Run smbpassword -a to set password for seb and franck, after creating local user

When prompted by windows enter the credentials.