# Share file from Ubuntu to Windows 8.1 using network or Homegroup

Tags: networking

I shared a file on my computer running Ubuntu I couldn't find it on another Computer that I shared it with.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: How did you share it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share files through the local network?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

Answer (score 2):

Nathnael, in order to share with windows you need to use samba. Look at this tutorial. There are many other tutorials that are similar.

[Samba Tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for your support but it didn't help me much. After creating a USERNAME  on the second step, got confused on the 3rd