# Connect two PCs via LAN

Tags: windows, lan, tcp-ip

One PC is running Windows 7, and another one is running GNU/Linux 16.04.
My goal is to transfer 75GB big data from one to the other.I have ethernet cable and I have already tried creating LAN(TCP/IP v4 protocol) on Windows and Linux also with these settings:

PC 1:
IP Adress: 192.168.0.2
Mask: 255.255.255.0

PC 2:
IP Adress: 192.168.0.3 (These IP's are different in one number)
Mask: 255.255.255.0

I plugged cable directly on these two PCs, but from one PC I cannot acces to other. I've checked file sharing in Windows.
After typing ping 192.168.0.2 in Terminal, I got:
$ ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.420 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.315 ms

So I have 2 questins:
1) How to connect these two and fulfill my task, i.e. transfer such big data without an external hard disc?
2) Are crossover and ordinary LAN cables the same thing?

Comment: To check connection; go to terminal (shell) on either (ctrl+alt+T on your Ubuntu, run pshell or cmd on other) and try pinging the other machine, eg `ping 192.168.0.2` if done from pc2. It'll confirm your machines are talking, and you don't need a special cable (normally a switch/hub reverses the send-receive pins; but most NICs autosense this & change). If you get a reply the connection is up, you only need to set up services (eg. file server where one will act as server to the other; SaMBa/cifs is easiest with windoze)

Comment: Results are best put in original question; ie. edit it and add there are more formatting options exist than in comments.  Your addresses are 0.2 & 0.3 in question; yet 0.100 shows in 'ping' so something is wrong.  to see your ip address you can enter `ip addr` or `ifconfig` (interface config) on your GNU/Linux, and `ipconfig` on your windoze box.

Comment: ICMP echo request (ping) is working so connection is good.   You need a protocol to transfer files such as SaMBa where a reference is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba?action=show&redirect=SettingUpSamba  When setup, SMB/SaMBa/CIFS allows you to create a directory for read/write on your Ubuntu box; which you mount (`net use` on widnoze) on windoze to copy files between machines. `scp` (secure remote-copy doesn't need mounting) isn't available natively on windoze but putty may allow it, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587036/using-putty-to-scp-from-windows-to-linux

Comment: NIC ports (network interface cards connectors) have a pin for sending data, and another for receiving data. A standard cable will connect the 'send' pin on one machine to the 'send' pin on another, where as a crossover cable swaps the send-receive pins so two machines can communicate directly. So crossover cables have pins 2 & 3 swapped on utp (unshielded twisted pair) cables. Connecting PC to PC should require crossover cables in theory. In practice most NICs have auto-sensing ports that detect this condition & make the swap electronically, so crossover cables are rarely needed

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/821477/can-i-plug-a-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-ubuntu-laptop

Answer (score 1):

re: crossover & standard cables

NIC ports (network interface cards connectors) have a pin for sending data, and another for receiving data. A standard cable will connect the 'send' pin on one machine to the 'send' pin on another so sent data gets lost (neither machine hears it). A crossover cable however, swaps the send-receive pins so two machines can communicate directly (hearing each others sent traffic). Crossover cables have pins 2 & 3 swapped on UTP (unshielded twisted pair) cable.

Connecting PC to PC should require crossover cables in theory; hubs or [network]switches do this function normally. However in practice most NICs have auto-sensing ports that detect this condition & make the swap electronically, so crossover cables are rarely needed on modern hardware.

re: your task

ICMP echo request (ping) is working so connection is good.

You need a protocol to transfer files such as SaMBa where a reference is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba?action=show&redirect=SettingUpSamba  . When setup, SMB/SaMBa/CIFS allows you to create a directory for read/write on your Ubuntu box; which you mount on windoze (`net use`) to copy files between machines.  When done you can unmount your connection & remove it (most secure), or leave it in case its needed again.

A faster/easier approach is just `rcp` (remote copy) or `scp` (secure remote-copy) doesn't need extra mounting steps, however isn't available natively on windoze.  A program called `putty` allows it so I suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587036/using-putty-to-scp-from-windows-to-linux  (this is more theory; I seldom use windoze)

Comment: You can cut the first paragraph from your answer. It is so outdated that it could be a sidebar at best, not a leading paragraph. [Auto MDI-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X) was introduced ~20 years ago and became mainstream ~15 years ago.

Comment: Part of the question was "*Are crossover and ordinary LAN cables the same thing*" - I was attempting to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, but I could not manage with samba and scp...
But at the end, problem solved!
 I used "HTTP File Server" for Windows to transfer data from PC which was using Windows 7 to laptop which was using Linux. Transfer speed was 5-5.5 MB/sec. In the other direction (Transfer data from Linux to Windows) I used "HTTP server"program(To install http server you have to install node.js and npm via console - it's easy ...), version for Ubuntu.