# connect a laptop to a desktop via Ethernet cable (both offline)

Tags: command-line, ssh, ethernet, offline

I have a laptop and a desktop

Two computers have Ubuntu 16.04 and connected through Ethernet cable, but two are offline, so no internet.
I wanna make the laptop as the main computer and I want to use the desktop by the laptop. Is is possible to control the desktop by using the laptop?

I am not sure if I could use SSH in terminal.. 
Could you guys explain me if there is ways?
or please give a hint or keyword so I can find a way.

Usually I use "ssh -X"

Thank you

Comment: Read `man ssh` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ssh.1.html , read `man ip-route` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/ip-route.8.html . You have an "internet", but it's a very small network.

Comment: Can you add more details to the question? Please edit the question and make it more specific. So you want access to the GUI desktop and graphical software like Firefox in your desktop computer? Or do you want command line only access?

Comment: See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821477/can-i-plug-a-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-ubuntu-laptop/821489)

Answer (score 3):

If you question is about the network, your answer is 'Yes'. You can set static IP on both your laptop and your PC. To do so, use `network-manager`:

1. Open Network manager
2. Edit LAN
3. Go to IPv4 Setting Tab
4. Set method to Manual
5. Set IP address.

[image]

e.g. set `192.168.1.1` for the PC and `192.168.1.2` for laptop.

Then you can use any network remote connection tool to access PC from laptop of vice versa. For example: SSH, AnyDesk, VNC Viewer, etc.