# How to quickly transfer files (using rsync) from a computer to another

Tags: networking, ssh, backup, rsync

I want to transfer the whole content of a partition from a computer tu another. The answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070447/transferring-stuff-from-one-computer-to-another) apparently solve the problem exactly as I wanted. But the result is too slow.

What I did:

I connected both computers to my home wifi, both have ip 192.168.... fine.

I started ssh service on one comuter,

from the other I lunched the command

```
rsync -av -e ssh 192.168.2.110:./ .
```

but it goes extremely slow (1MiB per second according to network monitor)

There could be many reasons for that.

How should I proceed to discover the reason and fix the problem?

If it is a wifi problem, how can I connect the computer so that they comunicate quickly?
If it is a rsync problem, should I use other programs, or is there some known trick?

**Update**: via ethernet cable the speed is 10 times faster. I did not succeded to have any fast wifi transfer (basically tryed to avoid routers via an adhoc connection) . Also, I didn't mount target partition with some particular option, and if I check with "mount" the only options I see are

```
(rw,relatime)
```

Comment: Wire would be way faster,

Comment: I just plug a eht cable on both and will work out of the box or do I need to perfome some setting? (unbutu 18.04 on one machine and ubuntu 20.04 on the other)

Comment: Also, is there a way to connect the  two machines by using wifi so that the connection is faster than 1MB/sec?

Comment: Take a look at a couple of questions: First try [this answer for how to connect two computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/310201#310201). If you want to connect two computers directly by an Ethernet cable, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821477/can-i-plug-a-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-ubuntu-laptop/821489?r=SearchResults&s=1|45.0467#821489). Otherwise connect both the computers to the router by Ethernet cables.

Comment: Did you mount the target partition with the `sync` option? By default (so if you don't specify anything), the mounting would happen with `async`. But if you have overridden it with an option manually, then that could be one reason. Mounting with `sync` makes writing extremely slow.

Comment: If one of the computers is a low-powered device, encryption can be a bottleneck.

Comment: FYI:  if you're currently using wifi, you can add ethernet cables to the devices during the transfer, and in most cases the system will soon detect they have a faster method of transfer and it will be used.  If a connection method drops, it'll switch to the other automatically (as long as another route exists).  You didn't specify releases, so this advice is generic.   (I've used it many times like you've described to find alternate faster routes during `rsync` though not always wifi is involved)

Comment: Update: via eth cable the speed is 10 times faster. I did not succeded to have any fast wifi transfer (basically tryed to avoit router via an adhoc connectio) . Also, I didn't mount target partition with some particular option,  I used the default and with "mount" the only options I see are (rw,relatime)

Comment: @user126154 you should either update your question with that info or [self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)