# 16.10 Nautilus options missing from menu

Tags: nautilus, 16.10

I am having trouble with Nautilus. When Nautilus is open I only have the word "Files" in the Menu bar. I believe from my research that this is normal. However when I click the word "Files" I get a drop-down with options - New Window, Sidebar, Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts, Help, About, Quit

I want "Connect to Server" to be there (and probably quite a few other things).

If I start "sudo nautilus" from terminal then I get a blank grey bar dropping down from Files like there are no options to show.

I believe I have the same problem as this https://askubuntu.com/questions/845273/nautilus-title-bar-menus-have-disappeared although they describe it differently

Comment: When you click on the files menu from `sudo nautilus` are there any errors ?

Comment: Output in terminal after sudo nautilus (before clicking Files)   (nautilus:5770): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(nautilus:5770): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: <broken file>:1:0: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/libgd/tagged-entry/default.css' does not exist

** (nautilus:5770): CRITICAL **: Another desktop manager in use; desktop window won't be created

Answer (score 3):

Was puzzled by this too, but it does indeed look like intended behaviour in [nautilus 3.20](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/nautilus-3-20-ubuntu-16-10) - which 16.10 ships with. From the screenshot in the link it looks like there is no longer an app menu in the title bar - "Files" is all you get. However, a menu is available via the icon in top right corner, which includes, for example, "Bookmark this Location" - which was previously in the title bar menu I believe.

In answer to your specific question on Connect to Server; this appears at the bottom of the window when you click on Other Locations:

[image]

Question in your link has gone btw.