# Sharing files between Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows-7, file-sharing, shared-folders

I have two computers, one is running windows 7 and the second is running Ubuntu.

My two computers are connected to a WiGi network. I want to make a directory in the Desktop where i could share files between Ubuntu and Windows 7, files like pdf , images ....

I have already looked in many discussions but I didn't find a solution.

Thank you

Comment: you can install ssh on both machine, and then you connect them (ubuntu -> W7 and W7 -> ubuntu)

Comment: or, you also can install samba on your ubuntu. Enable filesharing on W7, then connect to your W7 with `smb://yourW7ipaddress`

Answer (score 0):

You can install ssh server on your Windows Machine and connect by this protocol. [This is a tutorial how to do it.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/)

Comment: Please describe with more details in the answer, not only the link. You can also tell us if you have used the method yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying many discussion , this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network) worked well for me.
thank you guys.