# Install samba on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop

Tags: 16.04, samba

Trying to access windows share folder from Ubuntu 16.04 desktop and following dialog appears.

> smb Unhandled error message: Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory

I find out my default Ubuntu don't have samba installed when i try to install

```
sudo apt install samba
```

It failes with following trace

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: python-samba but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 is to be installed
         Recommends: attr
         Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: The `samba` package contains the server software. You don't need it to access CIFS resources on other machines.

Comment: there is a pretty good guide here; https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network

Answer (score 0):

First use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install`, then run `sudo apt install samba` again.