# How to share folders between two PC's with Ubuntu via WIFI

Tags: networking, 16.04, samba

---

Hello!

I try to share HOME folders between to PC with Ubuntu 16 via WIFI connetction.

I have followed this [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network). Now I see shared folders on each PC, but I can't access them. when I click on shared forlders on same PC or another PC, access popup appear and ask me Username, Domain (WORKGROUP as default) and Password.

I enter current user and password to access shared folder on same PC and username and password registered on another PC for shared folder on another PC. After press 'Connect' button this popup reset to default values without any errors/warnings. After press 'Cancel' it appear again and only after again 'Cancel' it dissapearing.

The only thing that is working is

```
ssh remote_pc_user@192.168.0.xxx
```

May be I have missing something in my settings for connect to shared folders in Files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SAMBA,

Complete tutorial here

[Samba Share Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21)

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 20.04, I can share a folder doing this:

- Right-click on the folder that you want to share;
- Goes to tab "Local Network Share" and check "Share this folder";
- If you don't want to use a registered user, you can check "Guest access (for people without a user account);
- Click on the button "Create Share".

[image]

Maybe some popup will appear to install the necessary software.

On the other computer you need to enter in your file manager e click on "Other Locations" (if you are using "Nautilus", it is on the left bottom corner) and access the Network from the folder you are sharing.

[image]

Comment: Can a Windows 10 user for example have access to this shared folder too if we're using the same wifi, please?

Comment: @ThunderBird, I can't test it now, but I think that the answer is yeas, because they use Samba to connect, but I can't guarantee

Answer (score -1):

By default `Home` Folder has only access to local particular user and other user don't have access to it at all. You can verify this statement by running `ls -lgH` in root folder. It is not recommended to share `Home` folder directly but if you still want to do it anyway. Changing it's permission through `chmod` might help.