# Copying files over from Ubuntu to Windows via Ethernet?

Tags: networking, ethernet, windows-10, 17.04

### Why?

I need to share some files (copy over) from my Laptop (running Ubuntu 17.04) to my Desktop (running windows 10). As the summed amount of files come to over 800GB and not wanting to do multiple trips with a 16GB flash drive I thought the next best course of action would be to connect the two devices together somehow. I chose to do it via ethernet cable as transfer should be reliable and the throughput should be decent.

### The problem

After connecting the 2 devices together and sharing all the relevant folders on BOTH systems they still don't seem to recognise each other nor do I seem to be able to find any simple solution to what I assumed might be a common occurence.

### Extra (but not necessary)

Tips on speeding up the transfer. I was thinking of potentially adding all the folders to a `7z` archive (only because I've had good results with it in the past) and save that archive on windows so that you transfer the archive (which would surely be smaller).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using setting up a [Samba](https://linux.die.net/man/7/samba)/[CIFS](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) share on Linux. They run on a network file sharing protocol that both Linux and Windows understand. Since the content can be accessed by both machines a "transfer" as you're thinking isn't absolutely necessary. In this case archiving and compressing data may not be necessary. However, if you were still planning on taking what was in the CIFS share and copying it locally then there would be some value to `7z`.