# How to debug WIFI connection between two Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I have made all steps from [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

I am able to connect to my PC1, if it works as WIFI router with its built in WIFI adapter, but if I connect it to my WIFI router, it has internet.

My second PC2 are connected to the same WIFI router too and has internet.

I know IPs of both. I can not connect with sftp in both ways.

In first case it says: *Oops! Something went wrong, Unhandled error message. Timed out when logging in.*

The PC2 says: *Unable to access location. No route to host*

my PC1's IP: 192.168.0.101, and second IP 192.168.0.102

How to find out what's wrong. I am really tired of messing up with USB flash drive and copy/move files with it.

I've wasted an hour for this with no result.

Words that Ubuntu/Linux is user friendly are real bullshit.

Comment: Quite possible that firewall is blocking communication on port 21 for ftp.  
is the ftp service running on your machine? Install nmap and do a `nmap localhost` to check that.

Comment: @AbelTom everything is open.

Comment: Then, I would suggest do a `sudo ufw enable` and `sudo ufw status` to see ssh and ftp status on both the machines. ufw-Uncomplicated firewall. Would be nice if you could show the output.

Comment: @AbelTom can something be with the router, that it doesn't allow me access computers? Or if both has internet, then both should be able connect each other?

Comment: ````user@pc:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```` @AbelTom

Comment: I'd like to advice you to remove the last sentence of your question, it doesn't add any useful information but probably keeps people away from helping you. It might also be a reason that your question will be down-voted. I agree that solving problems in Ubuntu/Linux can be a hard nut sometimes, but we should focus on the topic in our questions, comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your firewall that it should accept incoming connections from ssh and ftp. Try doing a `sudo ufw allow ssh` and  `sudo ufw allow ftp`, and ask for status. (`sudo ufw status`)

Comment: didn't help. I don't think it's FW issue because I can connect PC1 with PC2 if PC1 is router and broadcasts WIFI connection. Maybe something with my external home router? Can it be so? Thanks for you tries to help.