# Ubuntu 16.04, how can I share an unmounted disk/partition with windows machines in same lan?

Tags: 16.04, mount, samba, raid, sharing

I created a raid 1 mirror from two physically attached disks and partitioned and formatted the newly formed raid 1 drive. My question is: Can I share this raid 1 drive in my local lan with other windows machines in WORKGROUP without having to mount the raid 1 drive in my linux server itself and how would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the files, a partition must be mounted by some software.

You can mount the partition locally and then share the files and directories using samba (see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/310201/454520) for a graphical setup).

It is also possible to share the partition on the network, and then mount it remotely, for instance using [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI).

In any case, the partition will be mounted either locally or remotely.

Comment: How can I mount the raid drive?

Comment: And also, my linux machine does not show on my windows machines under "Network"

Comment: thanks, the issue was related to a problem with lvm in connection with my raid 1 setup. I corrected it and it works fine now.