# How to sync files with Windows Samba share from within Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

I apologize in advance if this is confusing (this is the best way I could explain it):

Is there a way for the files Person B is sharing with Person A to be saved on Person A's computer so that when Person B goes to work, they still have access to the shared files, and then when they return home the files are re-synced with the shared folder? (Person A and B are both not very tech-savvy, which is why they were using Local Network Share in the first place.) Since Person B has the files that are to be shared with Person A, how does one sync files with Windows Samba share from within Ubuntu?

Just to clarify - there are no issues right now with Ubuntu-Windows interoperability - this is really a general question about caching (if that's the correct use of the word) the files on Person B's computer until they can return to the Local Network for the files to be updated.

Comment: Since Person B's laptop is running Windows 10, and you want that computer to locally copy/sync the contents of the shared folder, this is not an Ubuntu related question. Simplest (not tech-savvy) way to sync folders may be to use Dropbox or something similar on both computers. Another way is to write a script (batch file?) in the Windows 10 laptop to sync/copy the contents of the shared folder. I don't know how to do this on Windows.

Comment: But I thought that it still applies since it doesn't matter if the other computer is a Windows machine. I was trying to provide as much information as possible. I thought there was a way to do this as a setting from the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I want to help you. You provided all the details and someone may have an Ubuntu side solution, but I don't.

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I was hoping for a solution on Person A's Ubuntu machine rather than the Windows machine.

Comment: To do it the other way round, you need to setup Ubuntu to access the Window's "Shared Folder". If you can do this see the Ubuntu -> Windows section of [this  answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/310201?r=SearchResults&s=1|40.3128#310201) to get started. Once you can do this. Edit your question and make it how to sync files with Windows Samba share from within Ubuntu.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95183/discussion-between-user68186-and-riyaad-azad).

Comment: Tonido is a possible alternative. https://www.tonido.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully connected my Linux machine to a number of different Operating Systems using samba. I don't remember the exact software I used, but with some quick searching, I found a samba client in the Ubuntu Software browser called **Smb4k**. There are also command-line utilities you could use.

In my opinion, however, the better options both in terms of scalability, ease of use, and cross-platform compatibility is a program called **Syncthing**. There is a Windows exe, it's in the Ubuntu Software store, or can be downloaded via apt-get, and there's even a mobile app version for your smartphone. It functions much like Dropbox, except you maintain control of your own data. You can set it up to work only over your home network, or over the internet using Syncthing's relay servers.

Comment: Do you know if with Syncthing, if I leave the local network, will my files still show up and be accessible or will I not be able to access my files (like the issue I have with Ubuntu Nautilus Local Network Share). Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Even if the connection is lost, the files that have already been synchronized will remain on the device to which they were downloaded. You can then go about your day, edit them, delete them, whatever, and when you get home it will sync the changes with the rest of the network.

Comment: Here is a [Getting Started Tutorial](https://docs.syncthing.net/intro/getting-started.html) for Syncthing

Comment: Ok. Oh well, guess there's no way to do the same thing with Ubuntu's built-in Local Network Share. Syncthing will have to do.