# unable to access location (failed to mount Windows share:permiss.denied) when trying to open a samba shared map

Tags: permissions, samba

On my AcerAspireone I have Windows7 and Ubuntu. I have installed samba in order to access my windows files over a network (from W10).
I mounted the windows partition and created a share of the windows map in that partition. On the Ubuntu system the partition is mounted in `/media/pp/Acer`.
I created a local network share for the Windows folder in `/media/pp/Acer` and called it WindowsAcer2 and checked the "allow others...."

My smb.conf is:

```
[global]

workgroup = WORKGROUP

server string = Samba

Server %v

NetBIOS name = ubuntu

security = user

map to guest = bad user

name resolve 

order = bcast host

dns proxy = no

[WindowsAcer2]

comment = W7dirWindows

path =/media/pp/Acer/

browsable = yes

writable = yes

guest ok = yes

read only = no

create mode = 0777 

directory mode 0777
```

I have access to the windows files when I go to the mounted partition by `/media/pp/Acer/Windows`, but I get the mentioned error when trying (on the same PC! with Ubuntu) to open the `Network/WORKGROUP/Ubuntu//WindowsAcer2` shared map.

Anybody can help me on this one?

Comment: try this guide : https://itsfoss.com/share-folders-local-network-ubuntu-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Is the "pp" in `/media/pp/Acer` your ubuntu local user name?

If it is change your share definition to this:

```
[WindowsAcer2]
comment = W7dirWindows
path =/media/pp/Acer/
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mode = 0777 
directory mode 0777
force user = pp
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

For an explanation as to why I suggest this please see my answer here:
[Share external hard drive between two Ubuntu computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155078/share-external-hard-drive-between-two-ubuntu-computers/1155201?noredirect=1#comment1921961_1155201)

Your mount point and the auto mount point for external "drives" have the same issue.

Comment: Yes pp is username. Thanks: Problem solved!