# File-sharing between ubuntu 20.04 machines broken

Tags: file-sharing

I have a desktop and a laptop--both with Ubuntu 20.04.  I configure both for file sharing and cannot open either from the other.

I get "Unable to Access Location"  "HTTP Server error"

What is up?

Comment: Have you tried the Ubuntu to Ubuntu solution [described in this answer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/310201#310201) Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1257202/edit) and add information about what methods you used to share files.

Comment: you mention http.  Are you using filezilla or ssh or what.  I think that basic ftp (port 21) is no longer standard.  sftp over port 22 is the way to go.  Do you know the IP address of both machines?  Do you have the ssh metapackage installed on both machines?

Comment: I have been implementing new, 'clean' Ubuntu 20.04 installs on two systems:  a laptop and a desktop. Both are wonderful and I've been working through my checklist of apps and tools.  I had thought that I was at the end of my list when, as an afterthought, I thought I'd better test file-sharing.

Comment: I simply followed the Ubuntu instructions to enable sharing and received what I posted.  It failed as posted.  I have tried both laptop to desktop and desktop to laptop. File Manager accepts a DAV URL, prompts for a password, then reports failure and internal http server error.

Comment: It's as though this was never tested???

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the new information you put in the comments. It seems like you are trying to use SAMBA for file sharing.  If this is correct you may want to check the first section (Windows - Ubuntu) file sharing for guidance. SAMBA is meant for Windows-Ubuntu file sharing. It should also work for Ubuntu to Ubuntu file sharing, but as you found out, may have some quirks. If you think this is a bug, please [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this s a real bug.  The problem goes away when 'Require Password' is turned off in the Control Window under Sharing->File Sharing.

Now, if only I knew how to report bugs!

Comment: Please see the link in my last comment.

Comment: If you have filed a bug report then pleas update your answer with a link to the bug report.