# Network File/Printer Sharing from Ubuntu to Windows 10

Tags: printing, sharing

How can i access my Windows 10 connected Brother printer and shared Folders in Ubuntu?

PS. Same Network

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please ask one question at a time. See the site [help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for guidelines of how to ask questions in this site. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/310201#310201) for sharing  folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CUPS Admin interface, `http:/localhost:631/printers` and click on the "Add printer" button. CUPS will let you search the local network (if Windows has shared the printer) or type in the IP Address or hostname of the Windows system. CUPS is the Common Unix Printing System (Common, in that everybody uses it).

Comment: Can you teach me how to do it? because it shows nothing when i click browse...

Comment: No. AskUbuntu is a question and answer site, not a tutorial site. That being said, ensure that Windows has the printer set as "Shared". "How to share Windows printer" is off-topic for AskUbuntu, but an internet search might help.

Comment: i did some searching through internet but none of it help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 3 things in Windows:

- Services.msc
- Windows features (turn off and on)
- Advanced sharing

Services are:

- Function Discovery Provider Host
- Function Discovery Resource Publication
- SSDP Discovery
- UPnP Device Host

Windows features:

- Enable smb 1.0 CIFS file sharing support check all of them

Advanced sharing settings:

- Turn on all printer sharing and network discovery in private and public network
- Change encryption to enable file sharing for devices that use 40-56 bit encryption