# what's the current best way to connect 2 Ubuntus together on wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, adhoc, wifi-direct

I'd like to migrate my old home from an Ubuntu 19.04 to a new laptop running 20.04. Normally I'd use ssh/scp,rsync and unison.
Can't use a cable as the new laptop doesn't have ethernet port. Not sure if a usb-c cable would work but I don't have one, so I'd like to do this wirelessly.

I've tried the following:

1. scp from one host to another(as I've done many times in the past) using the correct IP  address..  ssh won't connect and ping doesn't respond either.
   Both are connected to the same WLAN but they seem isolated- wondering if it's some firewall at play (which I haven't found traces off). My other suspect was router settings-  however pinging a windows box on the same wlan worked fine, which suggested the issue was specific to the Ubuntu boxes.
2. tried to set up a adhoc wifi connection in NetworkManager gui (following the howto here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc) . I also had success with in the past with other distributions, but as I remember then NM used to have more wizards/options to make this straightforward.. now just setting the same SSIDs and Ad-hoc mode didn't lead to successful connection. Couldn't find any up to date documentation/howtos for this either.

Wondering what is the current best way for either of the above, or any other quick and robust way to connect 2 ubuntus? (avoiding pendrives or uploading to cloud).
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: If they really can't see each other on the network, solve that first. Check their IPs, use the `ping` command. "The current easiest way to connect" is the least of your worries, as well as the second or third easiest and less current ways.

Comment: "solve that first" - yes that's what I was trying to do. As mentioned, ping didnt respond. Using ping on wlan implies that I checked the IPs. Also as mentioned, i could ping the ip of a windows box, and I used to have no problem with this earlier- so i started to suspect its something new and ubuntu specific..hence my question and hope to hear from some helpful folks.

Comment: There are several ways to transfer files between two computer on the network. Some are easy, and some aren't, some are current, and some not so much. ...not that it matters anyway, since none of them will work, if packets can't flow across. There is, obviously, nothing new and Ubuntu specific in 20.04 or 18.04 to block packets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

Comment: The question was not about transferring files - but to connect 2 ubuntu boxes wirelessly in a direct way - once that's sorted I can transfer files no problem (I usually use unison, rsync, or ssh).   I just explained 2 ways I tried ( a) connecting to local IPs on the wlan   b) adhoc networks... both worked in the past out of box), was wondering if people had more ideas to try with either or some other way.

Comment: @mikewhatever "There is, obviously, nothing new and Ubuntu specific in 20.04 or 18.04 to block packets."
well, obvious or not (not to me) - there was new firewall system installed on both 19.04 and 20.04 rather than ufw (which seems more commonly advertised)..it wasn't featured in the system config UI out of the box, but that's what caused the problem. Added my own answer, in case some else runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if it's some firewall at play (which I haven't found traces
> off)

The issue ended up being firewall related indeed. Yes I didn't see any obvious firewall settings on the 19.04 and 20.04 (having read about 'ufw' but that was not installed)... however it turns out that this - to me -  new service was running on both boxes: firewalld (https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-use-firewalld-on-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04/ )

So the solution was to move the wifi interface from the 'drop' zone on to the 'home' zone:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=home --change-interface=wlp61s0
```