# Is it possible to access media sharing in ( ubuntu ) from my mobile

Tags: android, file-sharing

I would like to share some files on my computer with my Android mobile phone wirelessly. What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: You can use Samba shares or Nextcloud, just to name a few - guess it depends on your usecase/scenario.

Comment: This might help it is an article on how to setup FTP on your phone. You will need FTP on the Ubuntu computer as well. https://www.guidingtech.com/use-ftp-server-file-transfer-android/#:~:text=FTP%20is%20a%20simple%20way,your%20PC%20is%20the%20client.&text=Even%20if%20the%20Internet%20is,use%20FTP%20to%20transfer%20files.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide's "Windows->Ubuntu" section: [How to share files through the local network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network)

This sets up a samba share on your ubuntu machine.

After this just download any 3rd party file-explorer with smb support on android (I use CxFileExplorer, but most have it) and connect to `//<ubuntu's-ip>/` (try your own login aswell as just anonymus).

Keep in mind the permission issue however, if you can see a file but not access it change permissions to 666 (`chmod 666 <the-file>` in the terminal) or even 777 if it's really stubborn. However I recommend you change that back to something sensible like 644 afterwards.